# Client side Meteor on Server with reactive coffee

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, meteor, serverside-javascript, meteorite

What's involved in running 'client' Meteorite packages on server?

I'm interested in using reactive coffee for rendering a newsletter on the server. Can't find any references to this though it seemed an intuitive option. How's this (meteor client>server and newsletters) usually done?

Here's the package.js from [zhouzhuojie / meteor-reactive-coffee](https://github.com/zhouzhuojie/meteor-reactive-coffee/blob/master/package.js) on github.

```
    Package.describe({
  summary: "Reactive-coffee for Meteor"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('jquery', 'client');
  api.use('underscore', 'client');
  api.use('coffeescript', ['client', 'server']);
  api.add_files('reactive-coffee/dist/reactive-coffee.min.js', 'client');
  api.add_files('main.js', 'client');
  api.add_files('rx.meteor.coffee', 'client');
  if (api.export){
    api.export(['rx', 'rxt'], 'client');
  }
});
```

Comment: You may also check out the [Blaze](http://docs.meteor.com/#blaze) library, part of the Meteor project, which has an isomorphic interface to rendering DOM nodes on the client, and to strings on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a contributor to the `reactive-coffee` project, and I'll mention that the HTML building features of the project use jQuery and a real DOM, and so it would not be possible at the moment to use that library server-side.

There is a project with a similar API, but intended for use on the server, [TeaCup](https://github.com/goodeggs/teacup/), which might fit your bill.

I hope that's somewhat helpful, if not let me know.